# Raise default error on_delete PROTECT with Django

Tags: django, error-handling, constraints

I've defined an `on_delete` constraint in my model like this:

```
cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente,related_name="cliente",on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

When I delete an order related to a customer it will raise an error but just raise a 500 error with:

> "Cannot delete some instances of model 'Cliente' because they are referenced through a protected foreign key: 'Pedido.cliente'"

and a whole common information, what I want if I can set up a custom message error when occurs this, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I did it with this, note I'm using a `DeleteView` for this matter:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    try:
        self.object.delete()
        data = {'success':'ok'}
    except ProtectedError:
        data = {'success':'violation_protected'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),mimetype="application/json")
```

Just import `from django.db.models.deletion import ProtectedError`and let the magic happens.

Comment: How do you display the `foreignkey` that is causing the `on_delete` error in the response?

Comment: I am getting error: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'`. How to address this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can handle this in your view:

```
if obj.cliente_id:
    error = "Can not delete this entry"
    # and show this error in the template
else:
    # delete the entry, or continue with delete view
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the idea for my solution :)

Comment: How do you display the `foreignkey` that is causing the `on_delete` error in the response?