# Django REST Framework with ForeignKey on_delete=models.PROTECT

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

when I try to delete Django model object that is ForeignKey in another model with option on_delete=models.PROTECT, the error returned is the normal Django 500 Exception HTML web page, how to make Django rest frame work return json response with the error, is there a way for DRF to do that by default or it should be customized?

Answer (score 1):

Raising 500 Exception is the expected behavior. You have to customize to have a custom error. You can refer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022372/raise-default-error-on-delete-protect-with-django)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error by using ProtectedError expceptions.
Like this-

```js
from django.db.models import ProtectedError

try:
    # Write here your code
except ProtectedError:
    # Return your customer validation error
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete `MSI Shafik` answer, specifically for django-rest-framework, you can override the `destroy` method to catch the exception and return protected objects in a response to handle an error message in your application.

**For example:**

```
from django.db.models.deletion import ProtectedError

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except ProtectedError as protected_error:
            protected_elements = [
                {"id": protected_object.pk, "label": str(protected_object)}
                for protected_object in protected_error.protected_objects
            ]
            response_data = {"protected_elements": protected_elements}
            return Response(data=response_data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```